How to change the p-datepicker language in version 19?
I'm using the p-datepicker component but I would like to translate it into French and Spanish. How can I do this in Angular/Primeng 19?

Use PrimeNG localization support
Import the Locales and Config
import { PrimeNGConfig } from 'primeng/api';
import { localeFr } from 'primeng/api';  // French
import { localeEs } from 'primeng/api';  // Spanish

Use it like this.
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private primeNGConfig: PrimeNGConfig) {
    // Set the locales as per needs
    this.primeNGConfig.setTranslation(localeFr); // French
    // this.primeNGConfig.setTranslation(localeEs); // Spanish
    }
}


When I try to import PrimeNGConfig from primeng/api an error occurs:
Module '"primeng/api"' has no exported member 'PrimeNGConfig'.ts(2305)
the same occurs with localeFr and localeEs
my version of both angular and primeng is 19:
"primeng": "^19.0.1",
